# calendar modificaton

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I have used calendar in my site in SP2013 & used many views now default appearance of view is like one after other in new row , I want to show all those views as a drop down list. e.g. for birthday if you select it from category there will be a drop down of views you created & when you select one it will shows events with those category.

Answer (score 0):

We solved for something similar by creating a custom list with three columns: Display Name (how it shows up in the drop down list), URL (the link to that particular view), and Show (a Yes/No field for filter purposes). Then we added an "I need to..." web part to the page pointing to that list.

Some additional details available here: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2009/01/29/managing-links-with-the-i-need-to-web-part-aspx/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using jQuery, using browser inspector, get the selector for views, detach it from there, create new select html element using jQuery and add these views, and add 'onchange' event handler to navigate same window to that location.